# The PHP code ignoring my first input

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I write this code to take the tasks and their no from user

```
<form method="POST" action="add.php">
 <tr> <td colspan="4">Tasks</td> </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="4">
 <div id="tasksInput">
 Task Name<input type="text" name="mytasks[]"/>
 No <input type="text" name="myvol[]"/>
 <input type="button" value="add" onClick="add('tasksInput');">
 </div>
 </td> </tr>
<input type="submit"/> </form>
```

Java script "tasksInput" function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 1;
var limitt = 100;
function add(divName2){
     if (count == limitt)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + count + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv2 = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv2.innerHTML = "Task " + (count + 1) + " <input type='text' name='mytask[]'>" +  "No <input type='text' name='myvol[]'/>";
          document.getElementById(divName2).appendChild(newdiv2);
          count++;
     }
}
</script>
```

when i click submit, he must store the task in db, lets say i will store 
A 1
B 2
C 3

in DB he will store only the Task B and C  and The no 1 , 2
Could you help me plz

here is my php code

```
$needs=$_POST['mytask'];
$no=$_POST['myvol'];
$N = count($needs);

if(! empty($_POST['mytask']))
{
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {   
        $needname = $needs[$i];
        $noneed= $no[$i];
        if(! empty($needname ))
        {
            $query2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO projecttasks VALUES('','','$needname',' $noneed','')");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wheres your php code there??

Comment: sorry i add it again :(

Comment: just try to print_r($_POST) at the top and see how many values r u getting.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['mytask'])` say?

Comment: after submitting try to `print_R($_POST)` on your action page just like what Suresh says..

Comment: Array ( [mytasks] => Array ( [0] => A ) [myvol] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) [mytask] => Array ( [0] => B [1] => C ) )

Comment: when i use echo var_dump($_POST['mytask']); i got this  array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "B" [1]=> string(1) "C" }

Comment: What is the form of the data you want? This one creates a mayhem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form contains this

`<input type="text" name="mytasks[]"/>`

and via JS you are trying to add this

`<input type='text' name='mytask[]'>`

names of these fields don't match. Therefore, on server you receive not exactly what you expect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but the issue seems like because of indices. And both JS and PHP starts counting from 0 for the arrays. Maybe this might be the error

Change this:

```
var count = 1;
var limitt = 100;
```

to:

```
var count = 0;
var limitt = 99;
```

Comment: Does not affect, still ignoring the first input